# In an Angular template, is there a way to throw an error if a variable is undefined?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular templates, if there is an undefined variable in a template, it will fail silently.

Some sample code below:

The controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  //nothing here
});
```

And the view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p ng-click="doSomething()">{{ data }}</p>
  <input type="text" ng-modal="input">
</div>
```

None of the variables get interpolated because they don't exist on $scope. The mistyped `ng-modal` (not `ng-model`) attribute will fail silently. This is undesirable behavior in development.

Is there a way to change that so that errors are thrown? I'd be okay with a monkey-patch solution to Angular for this.

Comment: The answer address the case where `data` is missing. However there is no way to detect that you wrote `ng-modal` other than creating such `ngModal` directive or running some dictionnary based error detector like (with jQuery) `$('[ng-modal]').each( ... )`

Comment: I dont think there is anyway to handle spelling error..If you spell the arribute wrong , you wont see the result. This is only the way

Comment: the real solution now is to just use Angular 2+ :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure a value is selected, by using `||` in the template. When using || to assign a variable, the first truthy variable will be returned. So in your example:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p ng-click="doSomething()">{{ data || "Data is not defined" }}</p>
  <input type="text" ng-modal="input">
</div>
```

This will have the message change from "Data is not defined" to $scope.data whenever data becomes defined. If you want an error, use the same approach but instead of a string, use a function.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p ng-click="doSomething()">{{ data || handleEmptyData(data) || "Data is not defined and handleEmptyData() also returned undefined" }}</p>
  <input type="text" ng-modal="input">
</div>

$scope.handleEmptyData = function(data){
    if(!data){ alert("Error, data was " + JSON.stringify(data)); } };
```